# SVG text elements causing layout thrashing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, svg, layout

I have a very large number of positioned svg text elements on a web page, the text content dynamically updates on scrolling as the offSet variable changes (see code below), using vue.js. This update is causing layout thrashing which I'm unable to resolve. All of my elements are absolutely positioned and sized using css. What can I do to prevent layout recalculations?

I have attempted setting text-rendering property to optimiseSpeed. I have tried setting visiblity to hidden and modifying the text node of each text element via javascript and then setting visibility back to visible but still causes a layout thrash. I have also tried setting textLength to a fixed size.

```
<svg class=svg :viewBox="viewBox" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <g text-anchor="end">
      <text v-for="index in tickCount" :key=index  width=2 height=1
            :x="width/2"
            :y="index + 1"
            >{{index + offSet}}m</text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Chrome performance tools show layout taking a large amount of time and dropping FPS to <30.

Comment: Are you using Vue?

Comment: yes, updated the question.

Comment: How often are you dynamically updating on scroll?

Comment: The offset variable is updated once per scroll event, causing all text elements to update. A quick test shows my mouse scroll events are triggered once every 20 - 60ms.

Comment: Is it necessary to update so often? Also, how many text elements are we talking here?

Comment: Perhaps you could update every N scroll events.  Or wait for a pause in scroll events before updating.

Comment: The rate of scroll events is not the issue, I require the render cycle to complete in <17ms to achieve 60FPS and my scroll events are triggering maximum once every 20ms.

Comment: There are approx 100 text elements. The final product will be very render intensive with other complex SVG elements therefore we can't afford to have poor performance any aspect of the build.